# Laravel Livewire: keep status of hidden/shown component between updates

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

So I have livewire components showing a left bar in my site with some search fields (text, description, etc.) and a zone of it which shows collapsed on first load (it uses jquery I believe - the UI guy did it):

```
  <p class="filterDropdown"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseStatus">Status
                        <span><i class="far"></i></span>
                    </a></p>
                    <div class="collapse show " id="collapseStatus">
```

It contains some checkboxes and it shows something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLKkw.png)

Now if I close it (e.g. by clicking on the Status string) and type something in the textbox (e.g. the name one) it of course start a new request which ends up with the update of the component itself, but now the Status box is in its default status, that is open, showing the list of statuses.

How can I keep track of the status of such a UI component?
I've searched the livewire doc, but I wasn't able to find much, I thought maybe I track each of these blocks and connect them with some livewire's component property, but I couldn't find much.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding a property to the component like so:

```
  public $statusGroupOpen = false;
```

and modified the view like follows:

```
<p class="filterDropdown">
  <a wire:click="$toggle('statusGroupOpen')"  class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseStatus">Status
     <span><i class="far"></i></span>
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse @if ($statusGroupOpen) show @endif" id="collapseStatus">
```

It works, the downside is that it's shipping a request everytime you open/close the block.

If anyone has a better idea, I'm listening. For the time being, the above code works.

Comment: Isn't shipping a request every time part of how Livewire works? Why is it an issue?

Comment: would be much better if you simply store ```show```/```hide``` in ```$statusGroupOpen``` instead of bool and simply use the value as class instead of using conditional every time the component re-renders.